# jQuery UI resizable Min width is too large

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In the following jsfiddle - I've reproduced an issue that I'm currently having with the jQuery UI `resize`.

When I try to resize the `div` that is currently `1px` wide - it automatically increases in size and as a result I can then not get it back don to it's original size (or any smaller than the newly created `div` size).

Has anyone encountered this issue? I tried tagging a `min-width: 1px;` in the `.css` but that had no effect.

CSS for the `1px` wide bar is below;

```
.Task
{
position: absolute;
height: 25px;
width: 1px;
background-color: Yellow;
cursor: move;
white-space:nowrap;
top: 0;
font-family: Corbel;
font-size: x-small;
line-height:2.5em;
text-indent: 0.5em;
z-index: 1;
border: 2px outset;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Thanks in advance,

http://jsfiddle.net/cyVYq/24/

Comment: In the jsFiddle you linked, .Task is not resizable and its width is 25px.

Comment: apologies - fixed now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close. You need to set `minWidth` in the `resizable` properties, and not in the CSS. [The default `minWidth` is 10](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-minWidth), but you can set it to 1 to get your desired behavior.

```
.resizable({
    //containment: "parent",
    minWidth: 1,
    handles: 'e, w',
});
```

The [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cyVYq/25/).