# unwanted move when resizing div width min-width property

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a problem with jquery ui resizable, I face this problem many times, It make me confuse, the problem is: The right side of the div moves when resizing. Why?
[image]

The problem occurs when I set min-width for the div.

This is the fiddle of my problem: [My fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/coolesterman/tbbmky4x/2/)

stackoverflow asked me to accompanied by code also it's not necessary but here it is:

```
$('div').resizable({
    handles: 'e, w'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18325384/5204964).

I should set the minWidth in resizable initialization so instead of min-width property in css. I should do this:

```
$('div').resizable({
  handles: 'e, w',
  minWidth: 50
});
```